# How to print the line number when searching for a string in multiple files

Tags: command-line, grep

I would like to know a handy command to search for some strings in multiple plain text files and show the line number where it matchs in the output.
ie:

```
grep -r 'hello' --include=*.js ¿?
```

output:

```
base.js  [4]
base.js  [13]
utils.js [27]
...
```

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-n` as an option to `grep`. Or combine them in one with recursive mode, e.g.:

```
grep -rn pattern path/to/folder
```

As the manpage of `grep` says:

> ```
>    -n, --line-number
>           Prefix  each  line of output with the 1-based line number
>           within its input file.  (-n is specified by POSIX.)
> ```

Example output:

```
temp/openssh/openssh-6.0p1/sshconnect2.c:1468:  sent = send_pubkey_test(authctxt, id);
                                         ^^^^
                                         ||||----- Line number
```